# Laravel 9 is returning HTTP ERROR 500 on development with config does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Working from localhost everything is fine until I pushed to a cloud hosting. It's returning Error 500 with this error message in the log file:

```
[07-May-2023 22:40:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "config" does not exist in /home/signalon/plagscan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:889
```

I have checked the config folder and everything is okay.

Comment: Have you installed the package `composer install`?

Comment: @Davidesk `composer dump` && `php artisan optimize`, for generating autoload files and clear/cache services.